# Excel 2013 horizontal secondary axis

Tags: excel

I have made a scatter plot and I want to have a secondary axis for the x-axis. It used to be easy to do in 2010, but I have no idea where Microsoft put this option in the 2013 version of Excel.

Comment: Please flag this for moderator attention and ask to have it reopened and moved to [SU]. If they move it but leave it closed, ping me; I can vote to reopen on Super User (although it will need four other votes). If the [SO] moderators refuse to move it, please just re-ask it on Super User. Either way, please post an answer at the level of detail of [Werner’s answer](//stackoverflow.com/q/22492786/1672723#22493667), but *correct* for Excel 2013. I’ve got a chart with dual X axes and dual Y axes, but my two X axes show the same labels, and I can’t figure out how to fix it from your comment alone.

Answer (score 11):

You should follow the guidelines on [Add a secondary horizontal axis](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/add-or-remove-a-secondary-axis-in-a-chart-HP010342149.aspx#BMsecondaryhorizontalaxis):

#### Add a secondary horizontal axis

To complete this procedure, you must have a chart that displays a secondary vertical axis. To add a secondary vertical axis, see [Add a secondary vertical axis](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/add-or-remove-a-secondary-axis-in-a-chart-HP010342149.aspx#BMsecondaryverticalaxis).

1. Click a chart that displays a secondary vertical axis.
   This displays the *Chart Tools*, adding the *Design*, *Layout*, and *Format* tabs.
2. On the *Layout* tab, in the *Axes* group, click *Axes*.

   [image]
3. Click *Secondary Horizontal Axis*, and then click the display option that you want.

[image]

---

#### Add a secondary vertical axis

You can plot data on a secondary vertical axis one data series at a time. To plot more than one data series on the secondary vertical axis, repeat this procedure for each data series that you want to display on the secondary vertical axis.

1. In a chart, click the data series that you want to plot on a secondary vertical axis, or do the following to select the data series from a list of chart elements:

   - Click the chart.

     This displays the *Chart Tools*, adding the *Design*, *Layout*, and *Format* tabs.
   - On the *Format* tab, in the *Current Selection* group, click the arrow in the *Chart Elements* box, and then click the data series that you want to plot along a secondary vertical axis.

     [image]
2. On the *Format* tab, in the *Current Selection* group, click *Format Selection*.
   The *Format Data Series* dialog box is displayed.

   Note: If a different dialog box is displayed, repeat step 1 and make sure that you select a data series in the chart.
3. On the *Series Options* tab, under *Plot Series On*, click *Secondary Axis* and then click *Close*.

   A secondary vertical axis is displayed in the chart.
4. To change the display of the secondary vertical axis, do the following:

   - On the *Layout* tab, in the *Axes* group, click *Axes*.
   - *Click Secondary Vertical Axis*, and then click the display option that you want.
5. To change the axis options of the secondary vertical axis, do the following:

   - Right-click the secondary vertical axis, and then click *Format Axis*.
   - Under *Axis Options*, select the options that you want to use.

Comment: The thing is that Excel 2013 doesn't have a layout tab nor and Axes group, but I have found the solution, you just have to change the type after you selected secondary axis from the plus button.

Comment: Good answer, if only the question related to Excel 2007 or 2010. In Excel 2013, there is a 'Plus' icon floating to the right of a selected chart. Click here and you'll be able to add any feature you want. Or click the Add Chart Element dropdown at the far left of the Chart Tools > Design tab.

Comment: Thanks so much. I never would have discovered this on my own! What an utter usability FAIL.

Comment: @crysis405 change the type from what to what?